# How to configure local rate limiter in Envoy?

Tags: envoyproxy, rate-limiting

I would like to enable the [local rate limiter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.13.1/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/local_ratelimit/v3/local_rate_limit.proto) for just one Envoy proxy without having an additional rate-limiting service in-place. The version I'm using is 1.13.1.

I've tried adding the configuration directly into the filter chains:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.local_ratelimit
        stat_prefix: local_rate_limiter
        token_bucket: 
          max_tokens: 1000
          tokens_per_fill: 100
          fill_interval: 
            seconds: 1
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/application"
                route:
                  cluster: application
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            typed_config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: application
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    health_checks:
      timeout: 2s
      interval: 5s
      unhealthy_threshold: 2
      healthy_threshold: 1
      http_health_check:
        # path: "/application/health/live"
        path: "/application/health/ready"
    outlier_detection:
      consecutive_5xx: 3
      interval: 5s
      base_ejection_time: 30s
      max_ejection_percent: 50
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: application
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: application-1
                port_value: 8080
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: application-2
                port_value: 8080
                
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
```

When launching the Docker container I receive the following error:

```
[2020-07-21 08:03:03.717][1][critical][main] [source/server/server.cc:94] error initializing configuration '/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml': Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:(static_resources.listeners[0].filter_chains[0].filters[0]) token_bucket: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields
[2020-07-21 08:03:03.717][1][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:595] exiting
Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:(static_resources.listeners[0].filter_chains[0].filters[0]) token_bucket: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've just figured out that each [filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.13.1/api-v3/config/listener/v3/listener_components.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-listener-v3-filter) in the filter chain requires a `typed_config` element which should match the type I'm intended to use. First, I've tried to refer to the [wrong definition](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/v1.13.1/api/envoy/extensions/filters/network/local_ratelimit/v3/local_rate_limit.proto#L19) in the GitHub repo and I received another error. But then I found another one in the [correct path](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/v1.13.1/api/envoy/config/filter/network/local_rate_limit/v2alpha/local_rate_limit.proto). So, every `typed_config` value should be one of the definitions under [`api/envoy/config`](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/v1.13.1/api/envoy/config) subpath.

The correct configuration for local rate-limiting is the following.

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.local_ratelimit
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.local_rate_limit.v2alpha.LocalRateLimit
          stat_prefix: local_rate_limiter
          token_bucket:
            max_tokens: 1000
            tokens_per_fill: 100
            fill_interval: 
              seconds: 1
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
...
```